# Client Side Cache google map

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps

I need to Cache the google map on the client side through the openlayer.I havent tried the client side cache yet and have very little idea about it too.

Comment: did you check out [Offline Storage Example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/offline-storage.html).

Comment: What have you done so far? What problems have you faced? What exactly, is your question?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe which part of my question didnt you understand ?

Comment: Have you seen the link Aragon has posted, and tried to implement it? Where are you stuck? Unless we know which stage you are stuck at, it would be very difficult to help you out.